# Mobile internet causing blocked styles and scripts

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, mobile

I have a site set up with an SSL. When browsing the site on WiFi there are no issues. When I switch to mobile internet all the scripts and styles are converted to http and get blocked. As a result the page does not render at all. It doesn't matter what device I'm using. I have tethered my phone to my Mac and the same blocking occurs. The site is built in WordPress and has the following redirect code in the htaccess.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Really at a loss here!

Comment: Are these all of your custom Rewrite rules? Do you have any that check user agents? How are you browsing to the site (http, https, www,  no www)?

Answer (score 1):

It was an issue with the SSL. It was fine with nearly all browsers but on Chrome on Android with a mobile connection it was blocking scripts and styles.